# How to read out Max values for a number of variables and form the mean using spatialy close values in R?

Tags: r, sorting

Ahoy,
below is a df similar to the one I have to work with but way smaller:
(I left out a lot of rows to make it easier on the eyes.)

```
x y variable values
1  1 5        a      9
2  2 5        a      2
3  3 5        a      9
4  4 5        a      8
5  5 5        a      4
...
22 2 1        a      7
23 3 1        a      9
24 4 1        a      7
25 5 1        a      10
26 1 5        b      7
27 2 5        b      8
...
48 3 1        b      8
49 4 1        b      7
50 5 1        b      2
```

The df above is created by an fluorescence plate reader which scans light intensity within an area by dividing it in into 25 sectors (5x5) and measuring each sector individually giving one value each. The order of measurements is upper left corner sector first and lower right corner sector last. To make it more graphical:

```
01 02 03 04 05

06 07 08 09 10

11 12 13 14 15

16 17 18 19 20

21 22 23 24 25
```

Filling in the values from the df given above (+coordinates), it would look like this:

(5)   ___ 9  -  2  -  9  -  8  -  4

(4)   ___ 7 - 7 - 2 - 5 - 3

(3)  ___ 5 - 4 - 7 - 8 - 9

(2)   ___ 6  - 6 - 3 - **5** - **9**

(1)   ___ 4 - 7 - 9 - **7** - 10

(y^,x>)   (1) (2) (3) (4) (5)

What I need is to read out the max value for each variable and calculate the mean of this value and the (up to) 9 fields surrounding it. In the area/"variable" above("a") the highest value of a sector is 10 in the lower right corner, which is surrounded by the values 5,9 and 7. Hence the Result I am looking for for variable "a" is 7.75 ((5+9+7+10)/4).

I imagine the code to resemble something like this (I am aware that this is not how you write r, but I don't know better):

mean(max value within variable,value at x(of max value within variable)-1,y(of max value within variable)),value at x(of max value within variable)-1,y(of max value within variable)+1) .....

The next issue challenge is that the instrument will perform scans of 96 areas (="variables"). And ideally I need a solution that automatically gives me this special mean value for every/all variables without me having to write the almost identical code 96times.

I know this is asking a bit much but I have been working on it for a while and I just cant come up with a solution or even a good way of googling it.

Thank you very much for any help!

Tim,

Ps: Using this R code creates a random version of the df I present above:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = rep(c(5:1), each=5),variable = rep(c("a", "b"), each=25 ), values = floor(runif(50, min=1, max=10)))
```

Comment: Can you please use the SO editing tools to improve readability of your code & text? I struggle to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I would have loved to but apparently even that is beyond me. I did however accept your improvement suggestions. TA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This updated answer will provide the mean value of the maximum value and it's up to 9 surrounding values, within each variable group.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create the function
get.means <- function(df){
  # Get a data frame of rows with the maximum value
  max.rows <- df[df$values == max(df$values), ]

  # Create an empty data frame
  means.df <- data.frame(variable = character(), x = integer(), y = integer(), value = numeric(), mean = numeric(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # Create an iterator for the data frame
  iterator <- 1

  # Loop through each row of the maximum value data frame
  for(i in c(1:nrow(max.rows))){
    # Get the x value for the current row
    x <- max.rows$x[i]

    # Get the y value for the current row
    y <- max.rows$y[i]

    # Set the range of x values to process based on the x coordinate
    if(x == 1){
      x.range <- c(1, 2)
    } else if(x == 5){
      x.range <- c(4, 5)
    } else{
      x.range <- c(x-1, x, x+1)
    }

    # Set the range of y values to process based on the y coordinate
    if(y == 1){
      y.range <- c(1, 2)
    } else if(y == 5){
      y.range <- c(4, 5)
    } else{
      y.range <- c(y-1, y, y+1)
    }

    # Get a matrix of the values from the original data frame, which are in both the current y and x ranges
    vals <- as.matrix(df[(df$y %in% y.range) & (df$x %in% x.range), 'values'])

    # Get the mean of the values
    mean.val <- mean(vals)

    # Insert the current variable value to the data frame for the new row
    means.df[iterator, 'variable'] <- as.character(max.rows$variable[i])

    # Insert the current x, y, value, and mean values for the new row
    means.df[iterator, c('x','y','value', 'mean')] <- c(x, y, max.rows$values[i], mean.val)

    # Increment the iterator
    iterator <- iterator + 1
  }

  # Return the final data frame
  return(means.df)
}



# Create a test data frame
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = rep(c(5:1), each=5),variable = rep(c("a", "b"), each=25 ), values = floor(runif(50, min=1, max=10)))

# Get the means for each max value within the variable grouping
df1 <- df %>%
       group_by(variable) %>%
       do(get.means(.))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. I do think that it is very much going in the right direction. However, it still leaves me with the problem, that i ultimately only want one value for each variable and have them all in one df. 

What I did realize thanks to you, is that my example was rather terrible. Not only were there several max values but also the example calculation I showed did not even use the max value of that specific sector. I tweaked my example and change the phrasing. I hope it is much clearer now. Maybe you could have another glance. Thanks!! Tim

Comment: I've updated my answer to work with the dplyr `group_by` function. It will now return a data frame, which has the mean value for the up to 9 surrounding values, for the maximum value within each variable. Note: If there is a tie for the maximum value within a variable group, then it will return both rows.

Comment: Wohooo. Thank you soo much! This is spot on as far as i can tell. The only thing I can offer in response is that I will try to get better at  coding and also stackoverflow formatting so that I can try to contribute to the community in the future! Thank You!!